# how to print the ip in the following code?

Tags: python

I am not able to print the IP inside the following IF condition

```
def call_openNMS_service(node):

      #print node
      url = "http://localhost:8980/opennms/rest/nodes/{}/ipinterfaces/{}/services"
      dict_urls = [url.format(i, j) for i, j in zip(node["id"], node["ip"])]
      print dict_urls
      headers = {"Accept": "application/json"}
      for url in dict_urls:
          x = requests.get(url, headers=headers, auth=("admin", "0p35"))
          parsed = json.loads(x.content)
          ##print json.dumps(parsed, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
          for i in parsed["service"]:
              #print i["serviceType"]["name"]
              if i["serviceType"]["name"] == "SSH":    # So if i find SSH i print the node[ip]
                 print node["ip"]  ## this is where it should just print the one IP which has SSH running
              else:
                 print "No IP found with SSH running"
```

but this prints me the dicts of ip , not the particular IP

```
node = {
    'ip': [u'10.21.204.174', u'10.21.205.148', u'10.21.50.153', u'10.21.50.192', u'10.21.50.198', u'10.21.51.149', u'10.21.51.158', u'10.21.51.200', u'10.21.51.252', u'10.21.52.202', u'10.21.52.53', u'10.21.54.12', u'10.21.54.149', u'10.21.55.132', u'10.21.55.176', u'10.21.55.239', u'10.21.56.169', u'10.21.56.48', u'10.21.65.106', u'10.21.65.125', u'10.21.65.34', u'10.21.67.131', u'10.21.67.179', u'10.21.67.194', u'10.21.67.230', u'10.21.67.249', u'10.21.67.45', u'10.21.67.70', u'10.21.68.127', u'10.21.68.180', u'10.21.68.73', u'10.21.69.200', u'10.21.69.38', u'10.21.70.121', u'10.21.70.56'],
    'id': [u'564', u'561', u'462', u'389', u'352', u'353', u'390', u'354', u'356', u'454', u'348', u'349', u'455', u'563', u'359', u'360', u'363', u'362', u'525', u'426', u'503', u'466', u'431', u'527', u'529', u'373', u'414', u'518', u'430', u'425', u'413', u'368', u'404', u'517', u'502']
}
```

Comment: Can you show what `node` is?

Comment: how is `node` created? before you make the request? (do you even need the hostname then?)

Comment: node is something i get from another function @Aaron , So basically node is a dict of 2 lists, namely IP & ID

Comment: It's your code and with `print node['ip']` you print the dict. Why did you expect the program to print only one of the IP addresses?

Comment: You could change: `for url in dict_urls:` to `for idx, url in enumerate(dict_urls):` and `print node['ip']` to `print node['ip'][idx]`.

Comment: @CristiFati Says TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written, the only place you have the individual IP in that `for` loop is embedded in `url`. Looks like you'd be better off looping over the `zip()` itself instead of using `dict_urls` as a middleman. Lose these two lines:

```
dict_urls = [url.format(i,j) for i,j in zip(node['id'], node['ip'])]
print dict_urls
```

Then modify your `for` loop to loop over the `node` elements and form your URL in the loop:

```
for nodeid, nodeip in zip(node['id'], node['ip']):
    nodeurl = url.format(nodeid, nodeip)
```

Replace all references to `url` in the loop with `nodeurl` (needed to change the name so you don't overwrite your `url` template). Then when you want to print the IP, just:

```
print nodeip
```

Here's how the final modified code would look:

```
def call_openNMS_service(node):
    url = "http://localhost:8980/opennms/rest/nodes/{}/ipinterfaces/{}/services"
    headers = {"Accept": "application/json"}
    for nodeid, nodeip in zip(node['id'], node['ip']):
        nodeurl = url.format(nodeid, nodeip)
        x = requests.get(nodeurl, headers=headers, auth=("admin", "0p35"))
        parsed = json.loads(x.content)
        for i in parsed["service"]:
            if i["serviceType"]["name"] == "SSH":
                print nodeip
            else:
                print "No IP found with SSH running"
```

Comment: this just overrights the last IP 10.21.70.56 & it doesn't even have SSH running

Comment: Only if you print outside the `for` loop. If you print inside it, you should see each as it loops.

Comment: can u paste your code edit in the answer, i am messing it up